# How to pass two separate action objects to reducers in redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple middleware to handle API response data that is a promise object.

Now, I want to pass two separate action objects to reducers after promise is resolved and the resolved data is formatted to a certain format.

But, I'm not sure how to pass two separate action objects from my middleware since 'return' can be used only once.

What is the appropriate way to handle this situation?

## Middleware

```
const asyncMiddleware = store => next => action => {

    // some codes here

    action.promise.then(response => {

        if (action.type === 'YYY') {
            //some codes here to format API response data.
            const newAction1 = { type: 'type1', payload: 'original data' }; 
            const newAction2 = { type: 'type2', payload: 'formatted data' };        

            // does this work properly?
            // I dont want to do this. [newAction1, newAction2] as I lose consistency.
            next(newAction1);
            return next(newAction2);

        }

        return next(action);

    });
};
```

Comment: Just a thought - You have a reference to the store, in my opinion you can simply use `store.dispatch` function: `store.dispatch(newAction1); store.dispatch(newAction2);`

Comment: If I call store.dispatch(), does the action object go through reducers ? or directy go into redux store?

Comment: It goes directly to the redux store, passing through the middleware chain and then getting to the reducers

Comment: whats the difference with next(action) if both let action objects go to store, passing mw and reducers?

Comment: If you're creating actions inside the middleware, and using `next` on them, they will only pass through the middlewares mounted after the current one in the chain. Meaning if your middleware is the second one on the chain, they will not pass through the first one. If you use `store.dispatch` you got through all of them. I hope I am explaining myself clearly :-)

Comment: oh thanks! i didnt know that!

Comment: when should i return in middlewares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those in the comments for providing an answer. I've just tidied it up and provided it in one complete snippet here. In general ***return*** the final action and ***manually dispatch*** any others.

```
const asyncMiddleware = store => next => action => {

    action.promise.then(response => {

        if (action.type === 'YYY') {
            const newAction1 = { type: 'type1', payload: 'original data' }; 
            const newAction2 = { type: 'type2', payload: 'formatted data' };        

            store.dispatch(newAction1);
            return newAction2;
        }

        return next(action);
    });

};
```